# How to issue a GET request with JSON using RESTinstance?

Tags: json, get, robotframework

I'm trying to implement some REST API testing with RESTinstance and the robotframework.  I need to issue a GET request and pass a JSON body that contains an API Key and another field.  When I try this:

```
  GET  /aaas/v1/getSevRules  ${getSevRules_json}
  Output  request
  Output  response body
```

the request shows my JSON in query and the body is null.  My application under test responds with "Invalid input:  EOF".

```
    "query": {
        "aKey": "4444100000",
        "environment": "OTE"
    },
    "body": null,
```

This seems like it should be a simple thing to do, but I don't see how based on the Keyword doc.

Thanks
Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [RestInstance](https://asyrjasalo.github.io/RESTinstance/) Library the [Get](https://asyrjasalo.github.io/RESTinstance/#Get) keyword does not support the Body part of the request.

When looking at the Requests Library it seems that its keyword [Get Request](https://bulkan.github.io/robotframework-requests/doc/RequestsLibrary.html#Get%20Request) does. However, I've been unable to provide a working example.